# Starting and handling multiple CountDownTimers in Android

Tags: android, countdowntimer

In Android, I need to start and display multiple CountDownTimers at the same time, on the same screen, one after another. How can I proceed implementing this? Will using threads help?

Comment: Can you clarify more? starting at the same time and one after the other?

Comment: The user needs to enter the no of timers he wishes to start along with the duration . The duration of the timers will be different. Now when he clicks on a start button , all the timers should starting executing . How can I handle that ?  We can think multiple timers as multiple activities done at the same time by the user.

Comment: Hi, I want to start countdown timer one after other is there any way to start when one countdown timer finish it's execution and other can start.

Answer (score 0):

you can define and array or list for each timer you want to run,
and define a timer that decrements them every second.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/443141

has an example on how to schedule tasks every second. In the method that gets
called every second, decrement the values of all arrays and update a text-label.

```
...
for ( int i=0; i < timers.length; i++) {
   if ( timers[i] > 0 ) {
      timers[i]--;
      // update your textlabel
   } else {
      // change the text color, flash,vibrate,...
   }
}
...
```

to reset a timer simply set a new seconds left value.